# Parallel.ForEach() missing list items

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

In my tests without using `Parallel.ForEach()`, 3500 records are processed.

But with Parellel a random lower number of records are processed each attempt.  (3402, 3375, 3471, etc).  I figured out that DBSet didn't support parellel programming, so I am moving my items into a list, then dealing with the list later. (not ideal)  Some of the records that are missed, are added to the List as null objects.

What am I missing?

```
       public int Execute(CalculateAutoClassRatesCommandRequest request)
        {
            int recordCount = 0;
            var autoClassCalculations = new List<AutoClassCalculation>();
            var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
            Parallel.ForEach(request.BaseCalculations, options, baseCalculation =>
                {
                    foreach (var autoClass in request.AutoClasses
                        .Where(autoClass => baseCalculation.BaseClassId == autoClass.BaseClassId)
                        .Where(autoClass => autoClass.AutoClassForms != null))
                    {
                        foreach (var form in autoClass.AutoClassForms)
                        {
                            recordCount++;
                            var calcRate = CreateAutoClassCalculation(autoClass.AutoClassRoundingRules, form, baseCalculation); 
autoClassCalculations.Add(calcRate);
                        }
                    }
                });

            foreach (var autoClassCalculation in autoClassCalculations)
            {
                request.AutoClassCalculationsDbSet.Add(autoClassCalculation);
            }
            request.ratingContext.SaveChangesWithChangeTracking(request.Identity);

            return recordCount;
        }

private static AutoClassCalculation CreateAutoClassCalculation(
    IEnumerable<AutoClassRoundingRule> autoClassRoundingRules, 
    AutoClassForm autoClassForm,
    BaseCalculation baseCalculation)
{
    var autoClassCalculation = new AutoClassCalculation()
    {   
        BaseCalculation = baseCalculation, 
        AutoClassForm = autoClassForm, 
        BaseCalculationId = baseCalculation.BaseCalculationId, 
        AutoClassFormId = autoClassForm.AutoClassFormId
    };

    var roundingRule = autoClassRoundingRules != null ? autoClassRoundingRules.FindMatchingAutoClassRoundingRule(autoClassForm.AutoClassId, autoClassCalculation.CalcRate) : new AutoClassRoundingRule();
    autoClassCalculation.CalculateRate(roundingRule);

    return autoClassCalculation;
}
```

Comment: a `List<T>` isn't thread safe. You're probably corrupting `autoClassCalculations`.

Comment: Use `BlockingCollection` or `ConcurrentBag` instead of `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one problem and one potential problem that I see in your code:

---

All threads are accessing `recordCount` variable directly. Although `num++` may look like an atomic operation, it is not. It is essentially equivalent to `num = num + 1`. Since this is executed in several CPU instructions, it is possible that a thread takes a value, and gets suspended before updating the value. In mean time, other threads increase the value, and once initial thread is resumed, it just places value it calculated based on old starting value. Instead of using incrementing operator, you should use [`Interlocked.Increment()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) function.

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref recordCount);
```

---

Enumerator of your collection may not be thread safe. If you are using a custom collection type parallel access to elements may iterate over them faster than you expect. This shouldn't cause problem you described though. It would be wise that you use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Comment: “Enumerator of your collection may not be thread safe.” That's not a problem, `Parallel.ForEach()` doesn't assume that the enumerator is thread-safe.

Comment: I've never used Interlocked.Increment() before, but now my recordCount is correct.  Thanks for that.  However, I am still getting null objects added to the collection.  Is there a similar Interlocked method to add items to a List?

Comment: I just tried out a ConcurrentBag instead of a List, and my other problem went away.  Thanks a ton!!

Comment: No problem Jonathan. @Svick, thanks for the info. I assumed they just used `MoveNext()`, `Current`, but I see now in implementation they handled this properly.